# How to create a chart (Like Excel) using Javascript using 64382 lines of JSON data. (No Chart.js or other things like that, just js, html or css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project due in a few hours and need to make a chart using 64382 lines of JSON data. I don't know very much about javascript, so I don't have any ideas. I have made a chart with javascript before, but it only used 3 lines of data. The chart is not like a bar graph or pie chart, but like something you would make in excel. In the code section I will put the chart that I made using 3 lines of data. The data I am using is found here: https:/drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1VtT_y34UCJ9lHHfSqrhaeDeU92CGyXb7

I haven't done very much, I can't find any resource that shows me how to extract this json data using a for loop. I think that is how I should do it. Like for (i=0;i < data.length; i=i+1) {. But I can't figure out how to now put this into my chart. I also have to check that there aren't like 5 Afghanistan's or Canada's or whatever, and so I need code to do that too.

```
<div id="printmytable"></div>

<script>

function buildmyTable() {

  var inventors = [{name:"Tim Berners-Lee",invention:"6xU & HTML"},{name:"Haken Wium Lie",invention:"CSS"},{name:"Brendan Eich",invention:"Javascript"}];

  // build a string variable with all the table code and data
  var mytable = "<table border='1'>";
  mytable = mytable + "<th>Inventor</th><th>Invention</th>";

  // loop through data table to add data
  for (i = 0; i < inventors.length; i = i + 1) {
    mytable = mytable + "<tr>";
    mytable = mytable + "<td>" + inventors[i].name + "</td><td>" + inventors[i].invention + "</td>";
    mytable = mytable + "</tr>";
  }

  mytable = mytable + "</table>";

  // get the div and substitute mytable data for it
  var placetoprint = document.getElementById("printmytable");
  placetoprint.innerHTML = mytable;

}

buildmyTable()

</script>
```

---

I want a chart that looks like something made in excel showing each country only once. I really have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified some of the actual data you want to display to include multiple countries with just a few entries. This way you can see how to prevent duplicate countries using an array to store those already displayed, and how to access the various nodes of the objects in your data array.

Look in particular at the if statement before it makes a new table row. There are definitely other ways to do this, but basically you just want a way to keep track of the countries you already displayed.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "dims": {
            "COUNTRY": "Afghanistan",
            "YEAR": "2016",
            "GHO": "Number of physicians"
        },
        "Comments": "Includes doctors</br> Data Source: Ministry of Public Health and other Ministries",
        "Value": "9842"
    },
    {
        "dims": {
            "COUNTRY": "Afghanistan",
            "YEAR": "2016",
            "GHO": "Number of dentistry personnel"
        },
        "Comments": "Includes Dentists</br> Data Source: Ministry of Public Health and other Ministries",
        "Value": "120"
    },
    {
        "dims": {
            "COUNTRY": "Canada",
            "YEAR": "2016",
            "GHO": "Number of pharmaceutical personnel"
        },
        "Comments": "Includes Pharmacists</br> Data Source: Ministry of Public Health and other Ministries",
        "Value": "1675"
    },
    {
        "dims": {
            "COUNTRY": "Mongolia",
            "YEAR": "2015",
            "GHO": "Number of physicians"
        },
        "Comments": "Includes doctors</br> Data Source: Ministry of Public Health and other Ministries",
        "Value": "9808"
     }
]
              


function buildmyTable() {

  // build a string variable with all the table code and data
  var mytable = "<table border='1'>";
  mytable = mytable + "<th>Country</th><th>Value</th>";

  // loop through data table to add data
  var countries = []
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (!countries.includes(data[i].dims.COUNTRY)){
      mytable = mytable + "<tr>";
      mytable = mytable + "<td>" + data[i].dims.COUNTRY + "</td><td>" + data[i].Value + "</td>";
      mytable = mytable + "</tr>";
      countries.push(data[i].dims.COUNTRY);
    }
  }

  mytable = mytable + "</table>";

  // get the div and substitute mytable data for it
  var placetoprint = document.getElementById("printmytable");
  placetoprint.innerHTML = mytable;

}

buildmyTable()
```

```html
<div id="printmytable"></div>
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help @JSONaLeo ! This works fantastic when I use the snippet of the json data you provided, but it doesn't work when I try to use the data for the cloud. Google sites embeds take forever to load when I put the whole dataset in the embed. How would I go about creating this chart when the data is being imported from the google drive like:

`<!-- import my data from Google Drive -->
<script src="https:/drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1VtT_y34UCJ9lHHfSqrhaeDeU92CGyXb7"></script>`

Comment: I'm not completely sure how you are trying to access the json data, but I think you'll need to either fetch the (valid json) data with something like jQuery's `$.getJSON(url, function() { // call your function here })` or something like require.js to import the json locally from a file `var data = require('data.json')`.

Comment: I figured it out. Stupid mistake that the google chrome console didn't tell me about. Thanks so much for your help. If you have the time to answer one last question, I was wondering. How would I go about styling the chart using css. Stuff like:
`border-collapse: collapse;`
or
`padding: 15px;`
or even colours and alternating colour patterns to make it less bland. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd probably add classes to the table and separate classes for anything you want individual styling applied to, then put styles either between <style> tags in your html or link a .css file where you style based around the classes.... for <td class="country">, do `.country { background-color: pink; }`  for pink cells! Or something

Comment: Here's a general reference for table styles: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp